# Crystal Reports C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a multitable c# report based on a database I have created underneath using SQL. I am using the following code to try and set the datasource and have tried many different variations but cannot get the information from my database to show up properly in my report. Any help is greatly appreciated. The dataset is populating. Additionally the single table reports properly fill with data only the multitable reports aren't working.

UPDATE: The report now shows data from one table using `report.Database.Tables["Invoices"].setDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["Invoices"]);` However using the same logic on the table that generates the detail lines does not show any data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace SureSalePos
{
    public partial class Reporter : Form
    {

        private PosDatabaseDataSet posDataSet;
        public Reporter(PosDatabaseDataSet dataToReportOn)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            posDataSet = dataToReportOn;
           //InvoiceReport ir = new InvoiceReport();
           // this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = ir.FileName;

        }

        private void Reporter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "";// "PosDatabaseDataSet";
            myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "";//"PosDatabase.mdf";
            myConnectionInfo.UserID = string.Empty;
            myConnectionInfo.Password = string.Empty;
            setDBLOGONforREPORT(myConnectionInfo);
            //this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void setDBLOGONforREPORT(ConnectionInfo myconnectioninfo)
        {
            InvoiceReport report = new InvoiceReport();
            report.DataSourceConnections.Clear();

            // For each table set the source from your dataset
            report.Database.Tables["Invoices"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["Invoices"]);
            report.Database.Tables["InvoiceItems"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["InvoiceItems"]);
            //report.Database.Tables["People"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["People"]);
            report.Database.Tables["Preferences"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["Preferences"]);
            //report.Database.Tables["Skus"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["Skus"]);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }

        private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated Code above September 22

Comment: do you get the data in the dataset or not even?

Comment: Yes the dataset does get populated properly with data

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions at all for this?

Comment: The single table reports work fine only the multitable reports are broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to set the login since you are supplying the report data.  Try the following:

```
report.DataSourceConnections.Clear();

// For each table set the source from your dataset
report.Database.Tables["TableName"].SetDataSource(posDataSet.Tables["TableName"]);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: This correctly displays the information on the report from the Invoices table (the primary table) but does not show any of the line items in the report which is the InvoiceItems table, the table has 10 count when i set it as a datasource and continues to have 10 once it is a table for the report

Comment: Is the 'InvoiceItems' table for a subreport in the details? If so, you need to set the datasource for the subreport(s).  If not, does the tablename match both the report and the custom dataset.  It's not that hard to dynamically bind data with Crystal Reports.  If a noobie not a big deal just need to know how to explain.

Comment: The table name does match, I'm not a noob in general but not that good with crystal reports. The invoice details section is not in a subreport, just placed inside the details section of my form layout. If using the IDE to edit the report it shows up as the correct linkage (ie InvoiceItems.Description InvoiceItems.Sku) but the report doesn't show these items even though the table when set as a datasource has rows loaded (I've confirmed using the debugger). And thanks for all your help!

Comment: I have posted the updated code, all of the tables are set but the ones that arent used are commented out, the preferences table also doesn't show data and is in the header of the report. The reason I used the same method name was just because it was convinient for testing the answer you suggested.

Comment: That code would work if your report was setup correctly.  You mentioned you had data from the preferences table in the header which tells me you don't know how Crystal Reports works.  Placing a field in the header would only show the first record, not the entire dataset.  Review how report sections are generated and make sure your tables are linked correctly.

Comment: The preferences table is built in such a way it only has 1 record ever and thats the only data I need from preferences. And the one i need the selection from is the invoice items table which is exclusively in the detail section

Comment: Apparently the details section was set to "hide" by default, after seeing this and unhiding it it works now, thank you for all your help!